# Unity get deleted scene back

Tags: unity

I did something clumsy and seem to have deleted a scene and all the game objects in my unity project.

I have the whole project under source control and so I think I should be able to get it back, but when I reverted to an older version of the project, I still couldn't see the scene.

Could I have done something to hide the scene so that I can't see it in the hierarchy?
What file(s) should I be looking for in the earlier versions of the project?

Comment: I think it's a simple .scene file

Comment: Awesome, that's the information I needed @Bálint

Comment: that's why you should a have version control system

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be simple. I hadn't deleted the scene, I just closed it, and was able to get it back by opening it from Assets/Scenes

Answer (score 0):

On deleting Unity assets there is a warning that the action is not undo-able. Nevertheless the deleted Unity assets (i.e. project files) can be restored from the Windows' recycle bin even if they were deleted from within Unity. I'm not sure about other OSes but I assume it would be the same.